# Azure Run/Publish Fail Reason or Exception Dump

Tags: deployment, azure, error-logging

I'm wrestling with the Azure Deployment process.  I have an application (many applications) that have run very-well-thank-you-very-much on my local machine, but when I publish and run them they often are "Initializing...." and then "Stopping..." because they've hit some error.

My question is:  How can I find out what the error was that stopped it from running?

I want to be able to capture or view errors that stopped the actual deployment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you actually find anything related to this issue? Azure is driving me nuts with this try and error to find out why the deployment is not working..

Comment: I'm afraid I NEVER found any solution to this.  Our project was a feasibilty test to see if Azure was ready for Prime-Time yet.  Our study came out as "No".  Too many thread limitations, database size limitations, too much opaqueness regarding what is going on.

Next time I try a cloud solution I'll go with Amazon's service I think!

Answer (score 0):

This is problem is normally caused by referenced assemblies - you will need to check that you have set the "Copy Local" attribute to true for any 3rd party assemblies within your project.

See the following [blog](http://blogs.staykov.net/2009/12/windows-azure-role-stuck-in.html) post for a more in-depth analysis of this issue.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but most of my resolved problems have had nothing to do with this.  What I'm after is a way of DETERMINING the error.. not troubleshooting it.